# TTS is not looping properly

Tags: android, text-to-speech

My requirement: To convert a list of strings into Text to speech.and the start of each string it should play a sound

Problem:Whenever I run this only the last one gets executed and also no music is played inbetween the strings? How should I modify such that the loop will go to next string only when the TexttoSpeech of first string is completed..

```
   for(int m=0;m<c1;m++)
   {    
       mp = MediaPlayer.create(Web4.this, R.raw.music1);
       mp.start();          
       tts.setOnUtteranceCompletedListener(this);
       HashMap<String, String> myHashRender = new HashMap();
       myHashRender.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID,"end of wakeup message ID");
       tts.speak(question1[m],TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH,myHashRender);
       tts.speak("Completed", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD,        myHashRender);
       mp.stop();
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

Store the index in a field, and only call the next speak() from onUntteranceCompleted() (except the first one of course).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding delay between each call, it might help.